# Android handle decimal

Tags: android, android-layout, number-formatting

I am using retrofit calls for getting API responses. Everything works perfect. But I am reading some price values in decimal like **5.60, 2.20, 3.33** etc. I am adding currency code with this and setting to the textview like below

(QAR + " " + total)

But the textview showing as **QAR 5.6, QAR 2.2, QAR 3.33**.

What could be the issue here? The last digit of **0** removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format()` as below.

```
textView.setText(QAR + “ “ + String.format(“%.2f”, total));
```

Comment: Hope your answer will solve the problem. But I can't use this. Because that decimal digits are dynamic from API. So converted data type String solved the issue. But I want to understand Why it is happening with retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.format` like below:

```
String.format("QAR %.2f", total)
```

And it's not an issue. Trailing zeros after decimal point automatically discarded during conversion

If you don't want the auto conversion then use it as `String` in your model and maintain throughout your whole application

Comment: Hope your answer will solve the problem. But I can't use this. Because that decimal digits are dynamic from API. So converted data type String solved the issue. But I want to understand Why it is happening with retrofit?

Comment: Then try to send it as String from server instead of double

Comment: I already solved it. I just wants to understand how the system works.

Comment: And it's not an issue. Trailing zeros after decimal point automatically discarded during transmission/conversion

Comment: Yes. But my requirement is whole app wants to maintain same number of decimal.

Comment: I have checked your JSON, it's getting the `value` as String, probably your model property type is double. Am I right? If so then make it also String

Comment: There is no auto conversion if you maintain it as String throughout your whole application

Comment: Now we converted as a String. Anyway issue solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Amsheer, If it helps you then accept the answer and hit upvote Please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

5.6 and 5.60 are exactly equal, hence system excludes the last 0 and displays 5.6.
Solution to this is a "Decimal Formatter" 
`new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(total)`.

There can be different format arranged to formal decimal number.

EDIT 1:

yes, retrofit library must not change that value as it is a string type.

Within the getter method of the model class.
Here "value" is of string datatype as api resp

```
public String getValue() {
            return "" + new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(Float.parseFloat(value));
        }
```

Comment: Hope your answer will solve the problem. But I can't use this. Because that decimal digits are dynamic from API. So converted data type String solved the issue. But I want to understand Why it is happening with retrofit?

Comment: Can you please give that part of api response here?

Comment: {
        "label": "Discount Value",
        "value": "1.40",
        "text_color": "#ed2290",
        "is_bold": 0,
        "is_line": 0,
        "is_minus": 1
      }